# how to replace foreach loop with for loop

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, linq, for-loop, ienumerable

I am looking for a proper syntax.  I am using MVC and in my view I need to loop through the model since I need to do some other things at different counts. I am a novice here and looked through tons of postings but didn't find the syntax.
Here is the code, which works:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<IEnumerable<MvcMysurvey.Models.Mysurvey>>" %>
<% foreach (var item in Model) {%>
            <%: Html.HiddenFor(m => item.ID) %>

And here is the code I need the syntax for to make it working:

   <% for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++) {%>
             <%: Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].ID) %>
```

Comment: What is wrong with using foreach?

Comment: Is it just the "loop count" that you're missing ? Is that why you want to have for loop instead ?
By the way, the For loop syntax seems ok to me. What's the problem ?

Comment: Why is it that a foreach isn't what you need? the two are very similar

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your model is of type `IEnumerable<MvcMysurvey.Models.Mysurvey>`.

The problem is that `IEnumerable<T>` does not expose an [indexer (`[]`) operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a3hd7ste.aspx).  You have two options for dealing with this inconvenience.

1. **Use an array or a list instead.**
   Arrays and `IList<T>` implementations do expose an indexer operator.  To use the indexer syntax, you need to convert your model to an array or other `IList<T>`.  So, just change your

   ```
   <% for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++) {%>
      <%: Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].ID) %>
   ```

   to

   ```
   <% var items = Model.ToArray();
      for (int i = 0; i < items.Length; i++) {%>
         <%: Html.HiddenFor(m => items[i].ID) %>
   ```
2. **Use the [the `ElementAt` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299233.aspx) method**

   While `IEnumerable<T>` does not expose an indexer operator, there is a LINQ extension method that does the same thing.  It is [the `ElementAt` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299233.aspx).  To use this syntax, you could change your code to:

   ```
    <% for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++) {%>
       <%: Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ElementAt(i).ID) %>
   ```

The array syntax will be almost certainly be more efficient though.

Comment: @user1456934, You can select this answer by clicking the checkbox to the left of my post.

Answer (score 0):

I think this may be what you're looking for? Your question isn't too clear but it sounds like you're looking to do something based on a condition that the count is equal to something. If that's the case you only need to add an if statement to check the count against whatever value you're looking for.

```
<% for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
<% { %>
    <% if (i == someCount) %>
    <% { %>
        <!-- Do Something Here -->
    <% } %>
    <%: Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].ID) %>
<% } %>
```

Comment: this did not work because of IENUMERABLE<T> as explained in the posting above